Entra and MIP Errror using C# .AccessDeniedException: The service didn't accept the auth token. Challenge:['']
Here is the error message I get, we are using a login and password to get the auth token
just not sure what permissions we need.
"Microsoft.InformationProtection.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException: The service didn't accept the auth token. Challenge:[''] HttpRequest.Id={E0C61208-D90F-49FF-83E0-2A17F8D3DB9A}, CorrelationId=0a882288-d5e3-4b7a-812b-a5dc5a779271, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile
at EmailSDK.Program.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\DaHacker\source\repos\EmailSDK\Program.cs:line 56"
here is the code I have it is from MS's quick guide
  MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File);
    
    // Create ApplicationInfo, setting the clientID from Microsoft Entra App Registration as the ApplicationId.
    
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = new ApplicationInfo()
    
    {
    
        ApplicationId = clientId,
    
        ApplicationName = appName,
    
        ApplicationVersion = "1.0.0"
    
    };
    
     
    
    // Instantiate the AuthDelegateImpl object, passing in AppInfo.
    
    AuthDelegateImplementation authDelegate = new AuthDelegateImplementation(appInfo);
    // Create MipConfiguration Object
    
    MipConfiguration mipConfiguration = new MipConfiguration(appInfo, "mip_data", LogLevel.Trace ,false);
    // Create MipContext using Configuration
    
    using (MipContext mipContext = MIP.CreateMipContext(mipConfiguration))
    
    {
    
        // Initialize and instantiate the File Profile.
        // Create the FileProfileSettings object.
        // Initialize file profile settings to create/use local state.
    
         FileProfileSettings profileSettings = new FileProfileSettings(mipContext,CacheStorageType.OnDiskEncrypted,
                                 new ConsentDelegateImplementation());
    
         // Load the Profile async and wait for the result.
    
        IFileProfile fileProfile = Task.Run(async () => await MIP.LoadFileProfileAsync(profileSettings)).Result;
    
        // Create a FileEngineSettings object, then use that to add an engine to the profile.
    
        // This pattern sets the engine ID to user1@tenant.com, then sets the identity used to create the engine.
    
        FileEngineSettings engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings("Dahacker@aol.com", authDelegate, "", "en-US");
    
        engineSettings.Identity = new Identity(Dahacker@aol.comm);
        IFileEngine fileEngine = null;
    
        try
    
        {
    
     
    
            fileEngine =    Task.Run(async () => await fileProfile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;
    
        }
    
        catch (Exception ex)
    
        {
     
    
        // Application Shutdown
    
        // handler = null; // This will be used in later quick starts.
    
        fileEngine = null;
    
        fileProfile = null;
    
        mipContext.ShutDown();
     
    }
    
    
            public AuthDelegateImplementation(ApplicationInfo appInfo)
    
            {
    
                _appInfo = appInfo;
            }
    
            public string AcquireToken(Identity identity, string authority, string resource, string claims)
    
            {
                authority = https://graph.microsoft.com/.default;
                var authorityUri = new Uri(authority);
    
                authority = String.Format([https://%7b0%7d/%7b1%7d]https://{0}/{1}, authorityUri.Host, "10462954-a52f-469d-9f83-8ac832d15e78");
    
                _app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_appInfo.ApplicationId).WithTenantId("10462954-a52f-469d-9f83-8ac832d15e78").Build();
    
                var accounts = (_app.GetAccountsAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
                string[] scopes = new[] { "User.Read.All" };
    
               // string[] scopes = new[] { "Files.ReadWrite.All" };
    
                
                var result = _app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, "UserEmail:Dahacker@aol.com", "Password: LetMeIn")
    
                           .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
                return result.AccessToken;
    
            }


Use powershell to help troubleshoot : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/troubleshooting?view=graph-powershell-1.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts
